# 24 hour currency exchange in Bangkok near train station

Tags: money, exchange, bangkok

I need to exchange British pounds to US dollars before my 5.50 am train to Cambodia. I'm already in the city and made a silly mistake of not exchanging during the day. My hotel does not do currency conversions.

Is there anything near the train station?

Comment: which train station is that?

Comment: It is possible to withdraw US$ in - at least from what I know - Siem Reap with you credit card. So don't exchange to much of you Pound, since they change from Pound to Baht to Dollar which is not so good.

Answer (score 2):

If you are departing from **Hua Lamphong Train Station** then you can exchange money there according to [IHateTaxis.com](http://www.ihatetaxis.com/airport/BK1-Hua-Lamphong-Train-Station/Hua-Lamphong-Train-Station-information-guide). I guess they will be open 24 hours, the ones at the airport are open 24 hours and I think they are open 24 hours in major train stations as well.

Furthermore, a quick Google search shows that most major train stations have either money exchange services and/or bank offices that do exchange services.

Answer (score 2):

Having now been and done this, I can say I didn't find any pure banks/exchanges open at 5am. However there was an exchange that did the same as my hotel doing a pound to bhat then to dollar conversion.